# Is there a way to control alias names in Slick?

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I'm starting out using Slick for a legacy db and I want to drive stuff by very simple unit tests on the generated queries. The alias names chosen by Slick is a bit annoying and I would very much like to be able to control them. Is there a way?

A failing test is probably clearer than prose:

`[info] QueriesSpec:
[info] ActivityGroup
[info] - should join with Crmcategory *** FAILED ***
[info]   "select [x2."id", x2."name", x2."crmcode", x3."name" from "activitygroup" x2, "crmcategory" x3 where x3."id" = x2."crmcategory"]" did not equal "select [ag."id", ag."name", ag."crmcode", c."name" FROM activitygroup ag, crmcategory c where ag.crmcategory = c.id]" (QueriesSpec.scala:9)`

Comment: Only my opinion, it makes very little sense to unit test the generated query output from slick, first because it's machine generated (can change quite a lot), second because I think the slick team/community has done quite some testing in all this time. It would make much more sense to add an integration test to check the output, or if you are worried about performance overheads introduce by slick (which anyway you cannot catch from a unit test), to use simple SQL or drop slick entirely.

Comment: I kindof agree, but this is a bit for personal learning purposes. I want to test drive creating the queries I need with as quick turnaround as possible, therefore preferably without integration tests. I trashed the idea of using a seeded inmem h2 because I realized I just want to look at the sql at this point.